# Magento 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I recently updated customer and order information on my dev site and then pushed it live (without updating the increment_last_id). Our checkout is no longer processing credit card orders and when I check the exception log I get these 2 related errors:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in /home/tebostorefixture/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228


Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_invoice` (`store_id`, `base_grand_total`, `shipping_tax_amount`, `tax_amount`, `base_tax_amount`, `store_to_order_rate`, `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_discount_amount`, `base_to_order_rate`, `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `store_to_base_rate`, `base_shipping_amount`, `total_qty`, `base_to_global_rate`, `subtotal`, `base_subtotal`, `discount_amount`, `billing_address_id`, `order_id`, `state`, `shipping_address_id`, `store_currency_code`, `transaction_id`, `order_currency_code`, `base_currency_code`, `global_currency_code`, `increment_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `hidden_tax_amount`, `base_hidden_tax_amount`, `shipping_hidden_tax_amount`, `discount_description`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-12-12 18:48:11', '2016-12-12 18:48:11', ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
```

At first, the error had been attempting to duplicate entries around 100000027 and was going up each time we tried an order. So I went into eav_entity_store and changed the increment_last_id to 1 higher than our last order (100000117).

I re-indexed and cleared the cache. But now I'm getting this same error except its trying to duplicate 100000001. No matter how many times I try it, it keeps trying to duplicate that first order number. I went back and checked and the increment_last_id is going up correctly with each transaction that we try, but this error of duplicating 100000001 continues.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

For some reason I was missing 3 rows in eav_entity_store. One of those rows was for invoices and was necessary.

I wasn't able to export/import the rows successfully from our old database so I copied down their numbers and manually created the tables with the appropriate numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to resolve your error:

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ; 
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ; 
TRUNCATE log_customer ; 
TRUNCATE log_quote ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary_type ; 
TRUNCATE log_url ; 
TRUNCATE log_url_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ; 
TRUNCATE report_event ;
```

Or

You can try following.

In app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php

Search for isOrderIncrementIdUsed method

In that method,

replace

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);
```

with

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => $orderIncrementId);
```

Hope, one of these two solutions will resolve your problem.

Feel free to ask for any other help!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both approaches and neither had an effect. When I ran the SQL string the server came back "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)." for every line. Also, if I run a transaction as "saved CC" it creates an order with the transaction number that it should have.

Comment: I just noticed that in eav_entity_store I only have one row and its for orders. Should I have another row here for invoices?